# M1 - PHP Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug'

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, xdebug-3

I want to install Xdebug in my local environment, I have followed Xdebug wizard, but after installation by command `php -v` I a got warning from above.

I have tried to install `arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug`, not working.

`which php` -> `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php`

`php -v` ->

```
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug'
   (tried: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug, 0x0009):
    tried: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug' (no such file),
           '/usr/local/lib/xdebug' (no such file),
           '/usr/lib/xdebug' (no such file)),
           /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so, 0x0009):
    tried: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),
           '/usr/local/lib/xdebug.so' (no such file),
           '/usr/lib/xdebug.so' (no such file))
   ) in Unknown on line 0
 
Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug' (tried: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/xdebug' (no such file), '/usr/lib/xdebug' (no such file)), /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/xdebug.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/xdebug.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.26 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2021 01:21:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.26, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

`php.ini`

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
zend_extension=xdebug
```

Any idea?

Comment: When you ran `arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug`, where did it install the file into? I am thinking that your warning is from a different location or installation.

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: It would have told you when you ran the command